# how to use on replace live (jQuery v2.0.3)

Tags: jquery, live

```
//<div class="test"></div>
$(".test").append('<div class="single">Items</div>');//some function
$(".single").on({//when in lower version "live" works fine
mouseenter:function(){
console.log("mouseenter");
},
mouseout:function(){
console.log("mouseout");
},
click:function(){
console.log("click");
}
})
```

but in 2.0.3 "live" is undefined,but "on" seems not to get the event
what's wrong,"on" is not more powerfull than "live"?
what i suppose to do,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is to define a scope for `.on` like:

```
//<div class="test"></div>
$(".test").append('<div class="single">Items</div>');//some function
$(".test").on({
mouseenter:function(){
console.log("mouseenter");
},
mouseout:function(){
console.log("mouseout");
},
click:function(){
console.log("click");
}
}, ".single")
```

Comment: Special thank all of you,you are all right,very good.but this remind me of the speed,How enthusiastic people,millions of thanks

Answer (score 0):

The event delegation syntax of on is `$(static-ancestor-element).on(event, dynamic-element-selector, handler)`

```
$(".test").append('<div class="single">Items</div>'); //some function
$(document).on({ //when in lower version "live" works fine
    mouseenter: function () {
        console.log("mouseenter");
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        console.log("mouseout");
    },
    click: function () {
        console.log("click");
    }
}, ".single")
```

Comment: .test is the father of the selector and it's already defined, using it instead of document would be faster.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan yes.... I used `document` because the OP's original markup was not given

Comment: it's given but appended to //, so it makes it unclear. IDK how did I see it :D